# Problem - Azure subscription co-administrator with no rights over the database

Tags: azure, administration, user-management

I have some problems with the Azure user management. Here is the case.
I am co-administrator of an Azure subscription. I can manage the hosting services and the deployments but when I get to SQL Azure, I need to enter invitation code for CTP, which is strange. When I log in with the Service administrator account there is no problem.

What can cause that problem and do you have any suggestions how can I cope with it?

Answer (score 2):

The SQL Azure is just a virtual database server. You can create another user with SA rights and give that that for co-admin functions.